Paris Taxi with children seats (from and to airport)
I'will be visiting Paris in august with my two kids (3F and 6M) and I've seen that there are flat rates for taxis from CDG, but I can't find any information about taxis with children seats/boosters or if it is mandatory for taxis to have children seats/boosters.
Do we have to book a taxi from the airport with child/booster seat?
Or should we book transfer with some other company (if so any recommendation would be welcome) ?
Or can we take a taxi from de airport without children seats/boosters (I would like to avoid this)?

Note that child seats have never been proven to be more effective than seat belts for kids older than 24 months: https://archive.is/5td32. So your kids should be just as safe with just a seat belt on - and legally speaking a car seat is not mandatory in taxis as per the answer by jcaron.

Though they do add some height. A small child might have the top of the belt closer to the neck. This is both uncomfortable for sitting and going to hurt in case of an accident.

At the risk of stating the obvious, have you considered taking the train instead of a taxi? It's easy and fast and almost certainly cheaper.

@GregHewgill Personally I mostly use the train and it would indeed be quite a bit cheaper in this case but it might be interesting to note that for a group or family it's not always that much cheaper. At the moment, a ticket from CDG to the center of Paris is €11.80, two adults and a child is €31.85. A 3-year old child can travel for free, if she were 4, the total would be €40, teenagers pay full price so a family of four would pay €47.2. Taxi is €56 for the right bank of the Seine and €65 for the left bank.

@GregHewgill A parent with kids of those ages is going to have a lot of baggage in tow, to say nothing of two young children. Making sense of an unfamiliar city's public transit system while wrangling all that is not as easy or fast as you might assume.

@JonathanReez: I asked a question on Skeptics Stack Exchange about the research you linked to, and it seems that the argument is not quite as cut and dry as the article makes it out to be.

Child seats and boosters are not mandatory in taxis in France:
Article R412-2 of the "Code de la Route"

(...)
III.-Toutefois, l'utilisation d'un système homologué de retenue pour enfant n'est pas obligatoire :
(...)
3° Pour tout enfant transporté dans un taxi ou dans un véhicule de transport en commun.

Most taxis do not have any. If you have one which matches current regulations you should be able to use it.
Some companies can provide taxis with child seats and/or boosters. For instance, G7 (one of the largest taxi fleets in Paris) offers the G7 Famille service. You can book one via their app (select "G7 Famille" in the list of vehicle types, then the number of baby seats and boosters). You'll probably have to pay a little bit extra (4 euros if you book it on the spot, more if you book in advance, which includes waiting time in case of delays).
Other companies may have similar services.
Note that as soon as you add restrictions/extras on a booking it may increase your wait time, especially at peak hours, and that the pick up spot for booked taxis may be in a different place than the regular taxi queue.
